# How do I setup the Azure Storage Emulator to listen on all interfaces?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is it possible to get the storage emulator to listen on every interface rather than the 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 2):

First off,

127.0.0.1 is IP Address not port!
Than take a look at

> %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
>   Azure\Emulator\devstore\DSServiceLDB.exe.config

it has 
configuration settings for all storage services. However, if you change the address of Storage Emulator, than you will no longer be able to use "usedevelopmentstorage=true" as your storage connection string. My personal advise is to not change the IP Address of storage emultator! Depending on the exact need for different IP Address, I would rather suggest testing/developing against real storage service.

Comment: I was thinking interface in my head. :-) Thanks for the info.

Comment: I am amazed how the people make fun for downvoting answers more than 4 years old.
Whoever you are, do let your ignorance influence your decisions. Eventhough this answer is so old, it is still valid witht he exception that the name of configuration file has changed a bit. But if you really want to solve your issue you will easily find it!

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It is meant as a local simulator for local development. It is only meant for local use, and is not written or tested to be a network resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this to work by editing the relevant config files.

Refer to the following blog post:

- [Host Azure emulator and table storage on local network](http://blog.piyushthacker.com/?p=24)